# Apple PNG Image Decompression

Tags: php

I have run into a problem with Apple's unfortunate decision to create a PNG file format that isn't actually a PNG file format. I pulled a PNG image file from an app IPA file and attempted to display it on a web browser and found that web browsers don't know how to display them and give an error. It took me some time to discover that the original, unzipped image was even the problem in the first place.

After researching the issue and doing a lot of poking around, I finally found this script as I don't have the knowledge to create a class to do what I need:

https://gist.github.com/juban/8397183

The author says this is a PHP scripted version that will turn an apple PNG file into a standard PNG file so that it can display properly. For added information, I am running PHP 5.5+.

My process of pulling out the image file goes like this:

```
if ($zip->open($ipaFile) === TRUE) {
   if($zip->locateName($iconFilePath.$iconFile) !== FALSE) {

      if ($iconData = $zip->getFromName($iconFilePath.$iconFile)) {

      $iOSNormalizer = new iOSPNGNormalizer();

      $iconData = $iOSNormalizer->getNormalizedPNG($iconData);

      file_put_contents($iconSaveFile.$newIconFile, $iconData);


      }
     }
    }
```

The iOSNormalizer is a class you can look at by clicking on the link I gave.

When I run it through the class I get hung up with the following errors:

```
Warning: zlib_decode(): data error in mypage.php on line 524

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 12840 in mypage.php on line 532

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 12840 in mypage.php on line 532
```

...These last two notices  are repeated a ton of times for a lot of different lines. What happens is the apple PNG file has its original widths and heights restored, runs into the zlib_decode() error, and then stops working. The outputted file is a blank white image with its original height and width. zlib_decode() is not documented well for PHP and I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I'm hoping someone can look at the class in the link and better understand why this may be happening. Thanks!

EDIT: To ensure it isn't anything to do with how I am pulling out the icon file from the IPA file, I tested the following code on the image attached at at the end of my question and I still have the same problem (again, see the PHP class in my link to see what the function getNormalizedPNG() does):

```
$iconFile = "/path/AppIcon40x40@2x.png";
$newIconFile = "/path/converted.png";

$iOSNormalizer = new iOSPNGNormalizer();

$iconData = $iOSNormalizer->getNormalizedPNG($iconFile);

file_put_contents($newIconFile, $iconData);
```

[Example PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTYpx.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example PNG file you experience this issue with?

Comment: I was able to successfully use the class file on a iOS PNG from an IPA in PHP 5.5 without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Trying to upload and I'm having issues. I'm wondering if it's something to do with my code? I'm not sure why it would be.

Comment: I ran a test with the file uploaded in my question above and the same thing is happening. See the simplified code in my edited post.