# file stored on s3 not rendering in browser

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, amazon-s3

I am copying an image that I extract from an .ipa file on s3. The file is getting move correctly but when every I try to view it in a browsers it appear to broken, in google chrome. If I download the file directly to my machine and open it appears perfectly fine. It also renders ok in Safari.

```
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
   Zip::File.open(tmp_ipa) do |zip_file|
   # Find Icon File
   icon = zip_file.find do |entry|
     entry.name.include? 'AppIcon76x76@2'
   end
   icon.extract(File.join(dir, 'AppIcon.png'))
     s3_icon = bucket.objects[icon_dest]
     s3_icon.write(Pathname.new(File.join(dir, 'AppIcon.png')))
     icon_url = s3_icon.public_url.to_s
   end
end
```

Comment: Try opening the local file in Chrome, does it render?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because [Apple uses a non-standard proprietary extension of the PNG file format for the PNG files in an iPhone APP](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703004720/http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format)), such as the `.ipa` you say it was extracted from.

The reason it works in Safari, is because Safari uses the OS's image decoding libraries, which do support this non-standard format.

There [are some conversion scripts out there](https://gist.github.com/juban/8397183), that [work with varying success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669835/apple-png-image-decompression).

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using the ipa_reader gem which has a `IpaReader::PngFile.normalize_png(data)` function. I just need to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely problem is that you didn't set the `Content-Type` to `image/png` when you uploaded your image to S3. Try this on the command line:

```
curl -i http://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/AppIcon.png
```

What's the `Content-Type` header? If it isn't `image/png`, set that at the time you upload.

Comment: The content-type is `Content-Type: application/xml`

Comment: A browser such as Chrome will only try to render a png file if the `Content-Type` is `image/png`.

Comment: It may be that your fix is a combination of this answer and [@AlexanderOMara's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27870133/166339)

Comment: Most browsers, including Chrome, are actually smart enough to render an image sent with the wrong mime-type, so long as it is used as an image (i.e. an `img` tag). A good thing to, since there are many badly-configured servers in the world. Setting the right mime is definitely a good idea, but the non-standard format is the major issue.

Comment: the content_type is being set but still doesn't render